# Macro to consolidate data from 2 different worksheets of each wkbook inside subfolders and show result in separate worksheets for each subfolder

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm doing an office project where i need to create a macro.

I have a folder with 30 subfolders each named after our branches. For example- Chicago branch, New York branch etc.  Each subfolder contains a number of workbooks and each workbook has a number of worksheet full of data.

I made a macro to extract a number of cells from the worksheet called "Menu" and one cell from the worksheet called "score" and paste it in a new workbook.

I have researched online and made two separate macros to get the data from the two seperate worksheets. But it only works if I select all the files I want inside a  subfolder.

I also found some code to access folders inside subfolders but I couldn't compile it with my current code. In addition, I couldn't join the two macros I made, so it'd require only one button instead of two.

Now, I need a macro which will ask me to select a folder and go to the subfolders and folders inside the subfolders by itself and consolidate the data in a new workbook BUT in separate worksheets based on the Subfolders( the branch named ones, not the folders inside subfolders.

The data extracted from workbooks in the folders inside subfolders need to be in the worksheet named after the subfolder.) The idea is to have to press the command button once to get all the data extracted from that folder and subfolders inside at once as its too hectic to use my code 30 times for 30 subfolders to get data of 30 branches.

"Macro for extracting data from the worksheet MENU of each workbook"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FileNameXls As Variant
Dim SummWks As Worksheet
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim myCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim RwNum As Long, FNum As Long, FinalSlash As Long
Dim ShName As String, PathStr As String
Dim SheetCheck As String, JustFileName As String
Dim JustFolder As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

ShName = "Menu"  '<---- Change
Set Rng = Range("B9:b13")    '<---- Change

'Select the files with GetOpenFilename
FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", _
                                          MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(FileNameXls) = False Then
    'do nothing
Else
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet for the Summary
    Set SummWks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'The links to the first workbook will start in row 2
    RwNum = 2

    For FNum = LBound(FileNameXls) To UBound(FileNameXls)
        ColNum = 1
        RwNum = RwNum + 1
        FinalSlash = InStrRev(FileNameXls(FNum), "\")
        JustFileName = Mid(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash + 1)
        JustFolder = Left(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash - 1)

        'build the formula string
        JustFileName = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(JustFileName, "'", "''")
        PathStr = "'" & JustFolder & "\[" & JustFileName & "]" & ShName & "'!"

        On Error Resume Next
        SheetCheck = ExecuteExcel4Macro(PathStr & Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'If the sheet not exist in the workbook the row color will be Yellow.
            SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 1).Resize(1, Rng.Cells.Count + 1) _
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            For Each myCell In Rng.Cells
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                SummWks.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "=" & PathStr & myCell.Address
            Next myCell
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next FNum

    ' Use AutoFit to set the column width in the new workbook
    SummWks.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("b2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Client Name"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Occupation"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Insured Location"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serveyed by"

Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Property Risk Scores Updated as at """

Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 27.75
Range("B1").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 16
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
Range("c1").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 16
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With

Range("b2:f2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If
For Each SummWks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

        lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
        SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            With SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
            End With
        Next i

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

                lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                Next i
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

"Macro for extracting data from the worksheet SCORE of each workbook"

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim FileNameXls As Variant
Dim SummWks As Worksheet
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim myCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim RwNum As Long, FNum As Long, FinalSlash As Long
Dim ShName As String, PathStr As String
Dim SheetCheck As String, JustFileName As String
Dim JustFolder As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean


ShName = "score"  '<---- Change
Set Rng = Range("f65")    '<---- Change

'Select the files with GetOpenFilename
FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", _
                                          MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(FileNameXls) = False Then
    'do nothing
Else
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet for the Summary
    Set SummWks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'The links to the first workbook will start in row 2
    RwNum = 2

    For FNum = LBound(FileNameXls) To UBound(FileNameXls)
        ColNum = 6
        RwNum = RwNum + 1
        FinalSlash = InStrRev(FileNameXls(FNum), "\")
        JustFileName = Mid(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash + 1)
        JustFolder = Left(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash - 1)


        'build the formula string
        JustFileName = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(JustFileName, "'", "''")
        PathStr = "'" & JustFolder & "\[" & JustFileName & "]" & ShName & "'!"

        On Error Resume Next
        SheetCheck = ExecuteExcel4Macro(PathStr & Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'If the sheet not exist in the workbook the row color will be Yellow.
            SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 1).Resize(1, Rng.Cells.Count + 1) _
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            For Each myCell In Rng.Cells
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                SummWks.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "=" & PathStr & myCell.Address
            Next myCell
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next FNum

    ' Use AutoFit to set the column width in the new workbook
    SummWks.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("g2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Score"

Range("g2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If

For Each SummWks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).Find(what:="Score", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "0%"

        lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
        SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            With SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
            End With
        Next i

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "0%"

                lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                Next i
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the folder tree structure you want to use?  It seems like you will need to use a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` with `Set rootFolder = GetFolder(path)` for the root folder, and then iterate over all the subfolders with something like `For Each oSubFolder in rootFolder.SubFolders` sort of thing

Comment: @Dave Sorry for the late reply.
Desktop>Branch data~X Branch>>INFO.xls
                                   ~Y Branch >> Company folder>> INFO.xls
                                   ~Z Branch>>INFO.xls

Does this help? Also i'm a new user and this comment isn't showing the next line gap. Just FYI X branch, Y branch, Z branch are Seperate folders inside the Branch data folder.

Comment: @dave thanks a lot for the code! But its giving me subscript out of range when i try to run it. My coding knowledge is limited to basic C++ i took in undergrad so can you please check where i am going wrong?

Comment: subscript out of range means you are going for an array element that doesn't exist.  You'll need to say where and when this error occurs in your code - step through it with F8 and see what line it throws the error on.  As for copying to different sheets, I've edited my answer to show how you can do this easily enough

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand the requirement.  Try something along these lines?

```
Dim oSheet 
Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oFso.GetFolder("Path to Desktop Branch Data folder in here")
Dim oSubFolder, oBranchWorkbook, oWorksheet, iSheet
iSheet = 1
For Each oSubFolder in oFolder.SubFolders
    Debug.Print "Looking inside " & oSubFolder.Name
    ' Set the sheet to copy to (1 on the first, 2 on the second etc)
    ' this would be better if the sheets were named for each branch folder
    ' as then instead of iSheet you could use oSubFolder.Name and it wouldn't matter if things were out of order for some reason...
    Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(iSheet) 
    For Each oFile in oSubFolder.Files
        If Right(oFile.Name,3) = "xls" or Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set oBranchWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(oSubFolder.Path & oFile.Name)
            ' Now you have the Info.xls from whichever branch folder we are in open
            Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu")
            ' Extract whatever you need from Menu to the current workbook, e.g.
            oSheet.Range("A1").Value = oWorksheet.Range("B1").Value

            ' Once you complete the Menu extract, change oWorksheet to point at Score
            Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Score")
            ' Extract whatever you need from Score to the current workbook, e.g.
            oSheet.Range("A1").Value = oWorksheet.Range("B1").Value

            'Once you have completed all the extracts you need, close the branch workbook
            oBranchWorkbook.Close
       End If
    Next
    iSheet = iSheet + 1 ' increment sheet counter
Next ' Move onto next subfolder and repeat the process...
```

Comment: Hey so sorry for bothering you again. I ran this code but its giving me "run-time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error" in the line "  Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu")  "
Just FYI I'm using excel 2007.

Comment: I might have figured out the problem. All the excel files inside the subfolders from which i want to extract data have different names. So I need a generic fine name reference like for example any file that has *.xl* in it, will be opened and data will be extracted from it. How do I do that?

Comment: If the files have different names, it might be easier to loop through all of them rather than use your `Dir` command...  I've edited the answer above to show how I would do it

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I just ran the code but instead of listing all the information row after row, it's pasting the information in just one row erasing the previous information that was extracted.
""" Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu")
          
            oSheet.Range("A1").Value = oWorksheet.Range("B9:B13").Value

      """   For example,In here i need the information from oworksheet (b9:b13) to be pasted on oSheet row 2 (a2:e2)  and the next set of information in row 3 (a3:e3)

Comment: So, for each worksheet you need to update the first empty row rather than just the A1 row.  You can get the first empty row of `oSheet` with the following code: `firstEmptyRow = oSheet.Cells(oSheet.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` and then set the data with `oSheet.Range("A"&firstEmptyRow).Value`

Answer (score 0):

@dave I'm posting this as an answer because it's too long to post as a comment. Can you please check which parts need correction? Thanks a lot!

Also I needed a code that will put the branch data in different worksheets. For example in sheet 1 will contain all the info I extracted from X branch folder,sheet 2 will contain all the info I extracted from Y branch folder.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim FileNameXls As Variant
Dim SummWks As Worksheet
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim myCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim RwNum As Long, FNum As Long, FinalSlash As Long
Dim ShName As String, PathStr As String
Dim SheetCheck As String, JustFileName As String
Dim JustFolder As String
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

Dim oSheet: Set oSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet to copy to in here")
Dim oFso: Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder: Set oFolder = oFso.GetFolder("Path to Desktop Branch Data folder in here")
Dim oSubFolder, oBranchWorkbook, oWorksheet
For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
Debug.Print "Looking inside " & oSubFolder.Name
Set oBranchWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(oSubFolder.Path & "*.xl*")
' Now you have the Info.xls from whichever branch folder we are in open
Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu")
' Extract whatever you need from Menu to the current workbook, e.g.
oSheet.Range("B2").Value = oWorksheet.Range("B9:b13").Value

' Once you complete the Menu extract, change oWorksheet to point at Score
Set oWorksheet = oBranchWorkbook.Worksheets("Score")
' Extract whatever you need from Score to the current workbook, e.g.
oSheet.Range("G2").Value = oWorksheet.Range("F65").Value

'Once you have completed all the extracts you need, close the branch workbook
oBranchWorkbook.Close
Next ' Move onto next subfolder and repeat the process...


If IsArray(FileNameXls) = False Then
    'do nothing
Else
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet for the Summary
    Set SummWks = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'The links to the first workbook will start in row 2
    RwNum = 2

    For FNum = LBound(FileNameXls) To UBound(FileNameXls)
        ColNum = 1
        RwNum = RwNum + 1
        FinalSlash = InStrRev(FileNameXls(FNum), "\")
        JustFileName = Mid(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash + 1)
        JustFolder = Left(FileNameXls(FNum), FinalSlash - 1)


        'build the formula string
        JustFileName = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(JustFileName, "'", "''")
        PathStr = "'" & JustFolder & "\[" & JustFileName & "]" & ShName & "'!"

        On Error Resume Next
        SheetCheck = ExecuteExcel4Macro(PathStr & Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'If the sheet not exist in the workbook the row color will be Yellow.
            SummWks.Cells(RwNum, 1).Resize(1, Rng.Cells.Count + 1) _
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            For Each myCell In Rng.Cells
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                SummWks.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "=" & PathStr & myCell.Address
            Next myCell
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next FNum

    ' Use AutoFit to set the column width in the new workbook
    SummWks.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("b2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Client Name"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Occupation"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Insured Location"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serveyed by"
 Range("g2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Score"

 Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Property Risk Scores Updated as at """

Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 27.75
Range("B1").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 16
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
Range("c1").Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 16
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With

 Range("b2:g2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If


For Each SummWks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

        lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
        SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            With SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
            End With
        Next i

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

                lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                Next i
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If


With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If

For Each SummWks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).Find(what:="Score", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "0%"

        lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
        SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            With SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
            End With
        Next i

        SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = SummWks.Rows(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                SummWks.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "0%"

                lastRow = SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                SummWks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = 2 To lastRow
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    SummWks.Range(Split(SummWks.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                Next i
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next

 Next

End Sub
```